# bootstrap ul not centering

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

at http://pledge500.net/who.php I have a section of the page that I simply can;t get to center, so I'm turning to the geniuses here to see if you can help me work out how to center this...

```
<div> 
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<?php do { ?>
  <li class="active"><a href="http://www.mcdowellunitedfund.org/agency_show.php?ID=<?php echo $row_AGENCIES['ID']; ?>" title="<?php echo $row_AGENCIES['NAME']; ?>" rel="dmxLightbox" rev="{group:'PAGES'}"><?php echo $row_AGENCIES['NAME']; ?></a></li>
<?php } while ($row_AGENCIES = mysql_fetch_assoc($AGENCIES)); ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post links to a web site. When that site changes or is gone the issues cannot be replicated and the question is of no use to future users with similar issues. Add all relevant HTML, CSS and Script as required to the post itself and if possible add a jsFiddle or similar to demonstrate the issues. Also, a benefit to creating a jsfiddle is that while creating an isolated example of the problem the issues can become apparent.

Comment: thank you so much, will remember that for future reference, the question was answered very well, and very quickly! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the CSS:

```
.nav-tabs{
  text-align:center; /* only add if you also want the top menu to be centered */
}

.nav-tabs > li, .nav-pills > li {
  display: inline-block;
  /* remove float:left or replace with float:none */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
.nav-tabs > li, .nav-pills > li {
/* float: left; */ REMOVE THIS*/ 
display: inline-block; /* add this */
}
```